# How to invoke Lightning Controller method when Flow Next/Finish button is pressed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, visual-workflow

I have a Flow with a custom Lightning component which implements `lightning:availableForFlowScreens`.

I want the Flow to invoke a client-side javascript controller method when the user uses the `Finish` button in the Flow.

I cannot seem to find any documentation that implies this is possible.

1. Is this possible?
2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the Flow footer and create your own navigation.

And run this from your JavaScript controller:

```
var navigate = cmp.get("v.navigateFlow");
navigate('FINISH'); // or NEXT
```